# Printing the results in the original order

Tags: java, dictionary

```
String[] numbers = new String[] {"3", "4", "s", "a", "c", "h", "i", "n", "t", "e", "n", "d", "u", "l", "k"};
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    String key = numbers[i];
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        int occurrence = map.get(key);
        occurrence++;
        map.put(key, occurrence);
    } else {
        map.put(key, 1);
    }// end of if else 
}// end of for loop
Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator.next();
    int occurrence = map.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + " occur " + occurrence + " time(s).");
}
```

This program tries to count the number of occurrences of a string. When I execute it I am getting the answer, but the output is not in the original order, it is shuffled. How can I output the strings in the original order?

Comment: There is an implementation of Map which is documented to preserver order. :)

Comment: **ahem** http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4):

HashMap doesn't guarantee insertion order. Maybe try LinkedHashMap

Comment: Read: Basic map/set data-structures normally make no guarantee about order of enumerated keys.

Answer (score 0):

Using java.util.TreeMap, it implements SortedMap interface, you can provide the comparator.
Use firstKey() to get smallest key, use it to getValue i.e count and remove it from the map and repeat the call from firstKey()

Answer (score 0):

Like davin mentioned use a LinkedHashMap.

Also you can use the "foreach" loop in Java and replace:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator.next();
    int occurrence = map.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + " occur " + occurrence + " time(s).");
}
```

With

```
for(String key: map.keySet()) {
    int occurrence = map.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + " occur " + occurrence + " time(s).");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use a different Map implementation (as per other comments). You can change a single line to do what you need.

from

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

to

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```